# cv2.findcontours not working consistently

Tags: python, opencv, contour

I have some issues with the opencv method findContours(), since it does not work consistently for me. My code works for some of my pictures, but not for others. I can't really find my mistake, but I am also new to python aswell.

So here is my first image:
[image: image1]
When i use a threshold and morphological operations it looks like this: [image: modified image1]  
When I use my code to detect the contour, it works just fine.  
But now there is the other image: [image: image2]  
With the same modification: [image: modified image2]  
And now the code does not find any contour except a single point, which is located somewhere outside of my geometry.  
Does anybody have an answer to this? 
Here is the code I am using:

```
im=Image.open(filename)
imarray=np.array(im)
roi=imarray[150:600,200:800]
ret,thresh1=cv2.threshold(roi,125,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
kernel=np.ones([5,5])
closing = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh1, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(closing, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
_,contours,_ = cv2.findContours(opening, cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
```

**EDIT** 
here is the output of thresh1 for the second image:
[image]

**EDIT 2**
Not "really" solved the main problem but managed to somehow make it work: 
I found that when I am adding a border to the image using `cv2.copyMakeBorder` the `cv2.findContours` method manages to find the border like this:
[image: box] 
and a second contour is found, that looks like this:
[image: extract]
so there is the form I was looking for, but I have to manipulate the data to get the intended result. 
This does not really solve the general problem, but it is a way to somehow still gain my structure...
**EDIT 3**
I just found a mistake in my code. In the further use of the contour data, the data is modified for fitting a spline. In the process I did not use `np.copy` to make a copy of the contour I wanted to retrieve. After implementing this in the code, I get my desired contour without using borders. So there was no problem with the `cv2.findContours()` method, just me being inexperienced in python. Therefore, the case is closed.

Comment: Please attach the output `thresh1`.

Comment: The `cv2.findContours` method only accepts `CV_8UC1` and `CV_32SC1` images. After reading your images, convert them to grayscale by: `imarray = cv2.cvtColor(imarray, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)`

Comment: The image is a grayscale image and is accepted by the 
cv2.findContours 
method. Additionally I get an error if I try to convert it with your method